# Find fraction of friend requests accepted using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables for a social networking site - one containing the names of the sender and receiver of all friend requests sent, and another containing the names of the sender and receiver of all friend requests accepted.  I created a dummy database with the following -

```
CREATE TABLE requested ( sender text(10), receiver text(10) );
INSERT INTO requested (sender, receiver) VALUES ('tom', 'jerry');
INSERT INTO requested (sender, receiver) VALUES ('tom', 'adam');
INSERT INTO requested (sender, receiver) VALUES ('tom', 'alice');
INSERT INTO requested (sender, receiver) VALUES ('anne', 'jack');
INSERT INTO requested (sender, receiver) VALUES ('anne', 'bill');

CREATE TABLE accepted ( sender text(10), receiver text(10) );
INSERT INTO accepted (sender, receiver) VALUES ('tom', 'jerry');
INSERT INTO accepted (sender, receiver) VALUES ('tom', 'alice');
INSERT INTO accepted (sender, receiver) VALUES ('anne', 'jack');
```

How do I show the fraction of friend requests accepted for each user?  For these tables, I want to see something like -

```
tom | 0.6666
anne | 0.5
```

Comment: You appear to have no primary key- which may prove problematic in due course

Comment: FWIW, a separate table for reciprocation is not what I'd do.

Comment: @Strawberry I agree. This problem was taken from a list of "practice interview" problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      sender, 
      count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM requested 
                                  WHERE requested.sender = accepted.sender) as 'ratio' 
    FROM accepted group by sender
```

**OR**

```
SELECT 
      sender, 
      (SELECT count(*) FROM accepted 
                       WHERE requested.sender = accepted.sender) / count(*) as 'ratio' 
    FROM requested group by sender
```

The top one will ignore senders that haven't had at least one reply.  The bottom query will show those.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join between the two tables so that you get all of the rows from the "requested" table and only the matching rows from the "accepted" table:

```
select
    r.sender,
    r.receiver,
    sum(case when a.sender is not null then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as fraction
from
    requested as r
    left join accepted as a
        on a.sender=r.sender
        and a.receiver=r.reciever
group by
    r.sender,
    r.receiver;
```